# dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, 16.04

Error while updating the system.
I try:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get purge
```

Output:

```
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.122ubuntu8.1) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.122ubuntu8.1) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.6.2

gzip: stdout: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.6.2 with 1.
dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 initramfs-tools
```

I have installed only one kernel version.

```
~$ ls /boot/
config-4.6.2      memtest86+.elf
grub              memtest86+_multiboot.bin
initrd.img-4.6.2  System.map-4.6.2
lost+found        vmlinuz-4.6.2
memtest86+.bin
```

I removed all unused kernels and headers (excluding the current running kernel):

```
sudo apt-get purge $(dpkg -l linux-{image,headers}-"[0-9]*" | awk '/ii/{print $2}' | grep -ve "$(uname -r | sed -r 's/-[a-z]+//')")
```

Disk usage:

```
:/$ df -h /boot
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1       472M  329M  119M  74% /boot
```

How to fix this?